# Sim Application Toolkit - cant display text (actually nothing) on selection

Tags: javacard, sim-toolkit

I try to develop a Sim Application Toolkit Applet.. Many simple examples found in internet, but no success..

The problem is;
My menu entry comes in the STK menu, but if I select it, nothing happens.. I try to display text on event EVENT_MENU_SELECTION. (Actually not only displaying text, also sms, ussd, sub items doesn't work too..)

- I have real sim cards from the manufacturer to develop and test some applets with the auth keys.
- I test it on a Android 2.3 NFC smartphone.
- To load the applet into SIM, I use ACR1281U as reader and Giesecke & Devrient JLoad 2.3.0 as loader.
- In the Sim Toolkit is default a menu entry, working fine.

Here is my sample code.. Hope anybody has an idea.. (Maybe some specific install parameter on loading applet?)

Thanks in advance,
Kutschka

```
package proactive_cmd;

import javacard.framework.*;
import sim.access.*;
import sim.toolkit.*;

public class display_text extends Applet 
  implements ToolkitConstants, ToolkitInterface
{
  private static final byte CMD_QUALIFIER = (byte)0x80;

  private byte[] menuEntry = {'M','y','M','e','n','u'};
  private byte[] textBuf = {'H','e','l','l','o'};

  private ToolkitRegistry reg;
  private SIMView gsmFile;

  public display_text() {
    //Get the GSM application reference
    gsmFile = SIMSystem.getTheSIMView();

    reg = ToolkitRegistry.getEntry();

    reg.initMenuEntry(menuEntry,
                      (short) 0, 
                      (short) menuEntry.length,
                      PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT,
                      false,
                      (byte) 0,
                      (short) 0);
  }

  public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength)
    throws ISOException
  {

    display_text dt = new display_text();
    dt.register();
  }

  public void processToolkit(byte event)
    throws ToolkitException
  {
    ProactiveHandler ph = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();

    if (event == EVENT_MENU_SELECTION) {


       ph.init((byte) PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, (byte) CMD_QUALIFIER, DEV_ID_DISPLAY);
       ph.appendTLV((byte)(TAG_TEXT_STRING | TAG_SET_CR),
                    textBuf,
                    (short) 0, 
                    (short) textBuf.length);
      ph.send();
    }
  }


  public void process(APDU apdu) {
    if (selectingApplet()) {
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get the STK development kit? Is it open like the jcdk you can find at Oracle's page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use STK commands you have to properly install your applet. For SIM Toolkit it has to be CA tag in INSTALL MAKE SELECTABLE command. If you'll use UICC toolkit you have to use EA tag. Please refer to [ETSI 102 226 standard](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102200_102299/102226/06.08.00_60/ts_102226v060800p.pdf) for full details.

Comment: Hello thank you,
ok, after making selectable, it works.. I can display the text..
I use the sim.toolkit, and have read the Global Platform specification. The selectable/install,..etc parameters are ok, but I couldn't understand the install tokens (the last part of the install parameter). Could you refer me please?

And my second question, I use the sim.toolkit, how can I use the uicc toolkit, where can I download it?

Thank you.